# How to check and unchecked box if the value is selected or combination of either?

Tags: jquery, rest, api

I have a working code that does the checking for each, checkbox and does the window.open using URL parameters to my channel in thingspeak. I want to check the combination of either if one is selected or not and must perfom the URL request to my channel in thingspeak. Here is the code that does that logic below currently.

```
 <div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="temperature">
    <label class = "custom-control-label" for="temperature">Temperature</label>
    </div>

 <div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input type = "checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="illuminance">
   <label class = "custom-control-label" for = "illuminance">Illuminance</label>
  </div>   
 <div class ="custom-control custom-checkbox">
 <input type ="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="button-state">
   <label class ="custom-control-label" for = "button-state">Button-State</label>


  // checking for per number of entries to read.
  $(function() {
    $("#download").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if($('#temperature').is(':checked')) {
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv');
      }
      if($('#illuminance').is(':checked')){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv');
      }
      if($('#button-state').is(':checked')){
        window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv');
      }

    });

  });

  // check combination of either

  // downloading the date range from start to end.
  $(function() {
    $("#download").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?start=2019-11-19%2019:11:19&end=2019-11-20%2019:11:20');

    });

  });

 //checking for multiple entries to read.  
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download').click(function() {
    var hcount = 0;
    if($('#temperature').prop('checked')) hcount++;
    if($('#illuminance').prop('checked')) hcount++;
    if($('#button-state').prop('checked')) hcount++;
      if(hcount > 1) {
        window.location.href ='https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?results=100&median=10';
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: And what is the question? Can you specify exactly what you want to do?

Comment: Not able to understand the question. Is there are three variant of click event of #download. 

Either one is selected : for this you can use if-elseif-else. That all I can understand from you ques

Comment: I want to know, how do you make other checkbox if you select 2 be able to download the correct data based on my URL parameter using window.open. It seems it uses the last function to download the feeds as CSV having multiple. Want to cater for 2 or one of either checkbox be able to download the correct data based on given URL paremeter. Meaning currently if i select 2 checkbox, the download uses 3 enteries instead of 2. I havent created that entry on my checking condition there. Why i need some help there, if you notice it does one per each entries and download that file as CSV

Answer (score 1):

I have checked your code and I have found that there is no download id in your dom that's why it does not work. If you replace **#download** with the **.custom-control-input** then this code will be working fine. I am sharing your code with some above updation.

```
<!---Downloading File using 
Jquery with Buttons---->
  <div class="form-group"><br>
  <div class="col-md-1.9 text-center">
   <button id="download" name="download" class="btn btn-warning">Download</button><br>
    </div> 
  </div>

<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" class ="custom-control-input" id="temperature">
    <label class = "custom-control-label" for="temperature">Temperature</label>
</div>

<div class = "custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type = "checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="illuminance">
    <label class = "custom-control-label" for = "illuminance">Illuminance</label>
</div>   
<div class ="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type ="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="button-state">
    <label class ="custom-control-label" for = "button-state">Button-State</label>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script>
        // checking for per number of entries to read.
        $(function () {

            $(".custom-control-input").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if ($('#temperature').is(':checked')) {
                    window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/1.csv');
                }
                if ($('#illuminance').is(':checked')) {
                    window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/2.csv');
                }
                if ($('#button-state').is(':checked')) {
                    window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/fields/8.csv');
                }

            });

        });

        // check combination of either

        // downloading the date range from start to end.
        $(function () {
            $(".custom-control-input").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.open('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?start=2019-11-19%2019:11:19&end=2019-11-20%2019:11:20');

            });

        });

        //checking for multiple entries to read.  
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.custom-control-input').click(function () {
                var hcount = 0;
                if ($('#temperature').prop('checked'))
                    hcount++;
                if ($('#illuminance').prop('checked'))
                    hcount++;
                if ($('#button-state').prop('checked'))
                    hcount++;
                if (hcount > 1) {
                    window.location.href = 'https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/899906/feeds.csv?results=100&median=10';
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Try this.